# How to format URL with query parameters for IGDB API?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api, curl

here is the documentation for the database I'm trying to use: https://www.igdb.com/api/v1/documentation

I requested a token from them and it was granted.

This URL works for me (I've written "redacted" in): `https://www.igdb.com/api/v1/games?token=redacted`

and it returns the following:

```
{"games":[{"id":1,"name":"Thief II: The Metal Age","slug":"thief-ii-the-metal-age","release_date":"2000-03-21","alternative_name":null},{"id":2,"name":"Thief: The Dark Project","slug":"thief-the-dark-project","release_date":"1998-11-30","alternative_name":null},{"id":3,"name":"Thief: Deadly Shadows","slug":"thief-deadly-shadows","release_date":"2004-05-25","alternative_name":null},{"id":4,"name":"Thief","slug":"thief","release_date":"2014-02-25","alternative_name":"Thief 4"},{"id":5,"name":"Baldur's Gate","slug":"baldur-s-gate","release_date":"1998-11-30","alternative_name":null},{"id":6,"name":"Baldur's Gate II: Shadows Of Amn","slug":"baldur-s-gate-ii-shadows-of-amn","release_date":"2000-09-24","alternative_name":null},{"id":7,"name":"Jagged Alliance","slug":"jagged-alliance","release_date":"1994-06-02","alternative_name":null},{"id":8,"name":"Jagged Alliance: Deadly Games","slug":"jagged-alliance-deadly-games","release_date":"1995-01-01","alternative_name":null},{"id":9,"name":"Jagged Alliance 2","slug":"jagged-alliance-2","release_date":"1999-07-23","alternative_name":null},{"id":10,"name":"Jade Empire: Special Edition","slug":"jade-empire-special-edition","release_date":"2005-04-12","alternative_name":null},{"id":11,"name":"Vampire: The Masquerade - Bloodlines","slug":"vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines","release_date":"2004-11-16","alternative_name":null},{"id":12,"name":"Vampire: The Masquerade - Redemption","slug":"vampire-the-masquerade-redemption","release_date":"2000-06-07","alternative_name":null},{"id":13,"name":"Fallout","slug":"fallout","release_date":"1997-09-30","alternative_name":null},{"id":14,"name":"Fallout 2","slug":"fallout-2","release_date":"1998-09-30","alternative_name":null},{"id":15,"name":"Fallout 3","slug":"fallout-3","release_date":"2008-10-28","alternative_name":null},{"id":16,"name":"Fallout: New Vegas","slug":"fallout-new-vegas","release_date":"2010-10-19","alternative_name":null},{"id":17,"name":"Fallout Tactics: Brotherhood Of Steel","slug":"fallout-tactics-brotherhood-of-steel","release_date":"2001-03-15","alternative_name":null},{"id":18,"name":"Max Payne","slug":"max-payne","release_date":"2001-07-23","alternative_name":null},{"id":19,"name":"Max Payne 2: The Fall Of Max Payne","slug":"max-payne-2-the-fall-of-max-payne","release_date":"2003-10-24","alternative_name":null},{"id":20,"name":"BioShock","slug":"bioshock","release_date":"2007-08-21","alternative_name":null},{"id":21,"name":"BioShock 2","slug":"bioshock-2","release_date":"2010-02-09","alternative_name":null},{"id":22,"name":"System Shock 2","slug":"system-shock-2","release_date":"1999-08-11","alternative_name":null},{"id":23,"name":"System Shock","slug":"system-shock","release_date":"1994-09-22","alternative_name":null},{"id":24,"name":"UFO: Enemy Unknown","slug":"ufo-enemy-unknown--1","release_date":"1994-01-01","alternative_name":null},{"id":25,"name":"X-COM: Terror From The Deep","slug":"x-com-terror-from-the-deep","release_date":"1995-01-01","alternative_name":null}]}
```

What I'm trying to do is figure out how to search by title. For example, if I wanted only games that have the term "Zelda" in it, how would I format the URL properly?

I've tried:

https://www.igdb.com/api/v1/games&q=zelda?token=redacted

which returns "forbidden".

I've also tried

```
https://www.igdb.com/api/v1/games?token=redacted&q=zelda
```

which returns that same exact list of games above, as if completely unaffected by the "Zelda" term.

Can anyone give advice on how to properly format this URL for performing a search based on Game Title? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query parameter should be passed with a "?" and the following ones each with "&".

The [documentation](https://www.igdb.com/api/v1/documentation/games#games_search_get) of the API says that you should query `/games/search` instead of `/games` directly. Please try this.

Comment: That's exactly the answer. Thank you, friend.

To clarify for any potential readers, the format is https://www.igdb.com/api/v1/games/search?token=redacted&q=zelda

Comment: what about v3? I'm confuse on how to construct the url. Due to headers. 
How can I access the games without adding header information?